# Does dereferencing an argument create a local copy of it?

Tags: c, pointers, memory

Please consider the following piece of code:

```
void bar(Thing* thing) {
    some_buffer[some_index++] = *thing;
}

void foo(void) {
    Thing thing;
    bar(&thing);
}
```

Does `some_buffer[some_index++] = *thing;` create a *copy* of the original `thing`?

Is this code guaranteed to be safe, in terms of memory? Because `thing` in `foo` is obviously dead when `foo` exits.

Comment: The code is erroneous as there is no definition for `Thing`, `some_buffer`, or `some_index`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does `some_buffer[some_index++] = *thing;` create a copy of the original `thing`?

Yes. It creates a copy of `*thing` and assigns it to `some_buffer[some_index]`, then increments `some_index`.

> Is this code guaranteed to be safe, in terms of memory? Because `thing` in `foo` is obviously dead when `foo` exits.

Yes. `thing` is in scope for the entire duration of these two functions, and `foo` does not pass the address of `thing` to its caller (as it's a `void` function).

Your code is completely valid.

Answer (score 3):

> Does dereferencing an argument create a local copy of it?

The below code *conceptually* creates a local copy and then copies.  The emitting code may simple read and assign in one step without an intermediate local copy - or may not - depends on the compiler.

```
some_buffer[some_index++] = *thing;
```

> Is this code guaranteed to be safe

No, not certainly.

`Thing` is not initialized, so depending on its definition, code may have traps or UB.  Best to post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

As the location of `some_index` and `some_buffer`'s data are unknown and may overlap `thing` in some strange way.  This obliges `some_buffer[some_index++] = *thing;` to take that into account.  Research `restrict` to negate this unlikelihood.  Better: avoid global data.

Otherwise, looks OK.

Comment: Per 6.2.6.1.6 "The value of a structure or union object is never a trap representation, even though the value of a member of the structure or union object may be a trap representation.", so assigning an uninitialized struct type object can never trap or have undefined behavior.

Comment: @ChrisDodd True, Yet `Thing` may not be a `struct`and so a _trap_ remains possible.  OP unfortunately did not provide a [mcve].  `Thing thing = { 0 };` would have set aside this issue.

Comment: However, per 6.5.16.1.3, "If the value being stored in an object is read from another object that overlaps in any way the storage of the first object, then the overlap shall be exact and the two objects shall have qualified or unqualified versions of a compatible type; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.", so if overlaps are possible, it is definitely a problem, but doesn't require anything extra from the compiler.

Comment: @ChrisDodd It was OP's "code guaranteed to be safe" that started my concern over these side issues.  It is one thing to look locally at `some_buffer[some_index++] = *thing;` as see no _usual_ problems.  I was qualifying the entire code - supposing what the remaining unseen code could be to render a "guarantee" assessment of "No, not certainly.".  Thanks for the cites.